# Testing an abstracted if conditional

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I'm trying to figure out the best way to test `find_communities` here without resorting to using polymorphism here to defeat the `if` statement staring at me.

```rb
class CommunityFinder
  def initialize(filters={})
    @filters = filters
  end

  def find_communities
     return my_communities if @filters[:my_communities]
     visible_communities
  end

  def my_communities
     # [...]
  end

  def visibile_communities
     # [...]
  end
end
```

I have both `my_communities` and `visible_communities` well tested, but I have concerns about testing `find_communities`.

1. I don't want to duplicate the test setup for both `my_communities` and `visible_communities`, because there's likely going to be
2. I would prefer for the class API to contain all 3 public methods because the conditions for `find_communities` won't ever change.
3. I'm writing this with the expectation that the class is going to change by someone other than me in the near future, and that there's going to be more methods

Should I:

1. make `find_communities` live in the caller
2. make `find_communities` be it's own strategy
3. duplicate the tests into `find_communities`
4. pick your own 4th option.

Comment: As a note, you can use Single-Table Inheritance (STI) without needing polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is a case where you really should have two subclasses, each of which implements its own `communities` method:

```
class CommunityFinder::Base
  def initialize(**options)
    @options = options
  end
end

class CommunityFinder::Mine < CommunityFinder::Base
  def communities
  end
end

class CommunityFinder::Visible < CommunityFinder::Base
  def communities
  end
end
```

You can use a factory method to instantiate the correct subclass:

```
module CommunityFinder
  def self.filter(**options)
    if (options[:my_communities])
      CommunityFinder::Mine.new(options)
    else
      CommunityFinder::Visible.new(options)
    end
  end
end
```